# Get download progress in Node.js with request

Tags: node.js, download, request, progress

I'm creating an updater that downloads application files using the Node module `request`. How can I use `chunk.length` to estimate the remaining file size? Here's part of my code:

```
var file_url = 'http://foo.com/bar.zip';
var out = fs.createWriteStream('baz.zip');

var req = request({
    method: 'GET',
    uri: file_url
});

req.pipe(out);

req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log(chunk.length);
});

req.on('end', function() {
    //Do something
});
```

Comment: i have inside .zip : node-webkit.app / and when i extract data-> CAN'T run  .app anymore: / my code::   fs.writeFileSync(frameZipFilePath, data, "binary");var zip = new AdmZip(frameZipFilePath); zip.extractAllTo(path.resolve("", "tmp"), true);

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This should get you the total you want:

```
req.on( 'response', function ( data ) {
    console.log( data.headers[ 'content-length' ] );
} );
```

I get a content length of `9404541`

Comment: Thanks! Is that length in bytes?

Comment: Yes. It's i bytes.

Answer (score 21):

```
function download(url, callback, encoding){
        var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
            if (encoding){
                response.setEncoding(encoding);
            }
            var len = parseInt(response.headers['content-length'], 10);
            var body = "";
            var cur = 0;
            var obj = document.getElementById('js-progress');
            var total = len / 1048576; //1048576 - bytes in  1Megabyte

            response.on("data", function(chunk) {
                body += chunk;
                cur += chunk.length;
                obj.innerHTML = "Downloading " + (100.0 * cur / len).toFixed(2) + "% " + (cur / 1048576).toFixed(2) + " mb\r" + ".<br/> Total size: " + total.toFixed(2) + " mb";
            });

            response.on("end", function() {
                callback(body);
                obj.innerHTML = "Downloading complete";
            });

            request.on("error", function(e){
                console.log("Error: " + e.message);
            });

        });
    };
```

Comment: Where does `1048576` come from? Is this a cosmic constant?

Comment: however for chunked response i.e. big stream containing multiple chunks skips the content-length header. What do we do then?

Comment: 1048576 is 1024 squared

Comment: the amount of bytes in one megabyte

Answer (score 13):

If you are using "request" module and want to display downloading percentage without using any extra module, you can use the following code:

```
function getInstallerFile (installerfileURL,installerfilename) {

    // Variable to save downloading progress
    var received_bytes = 0;
    var total_bytes = 0;

    var outStream = fs.createWriteStream(installerfilename);
    
    request
        .get(installerfileURL)
            .on('error', function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            })
            .on('response', function(data) {
                total_bytes = parseInt(data.headers['content-length']);
            })
            .on('data', function(chunk) {
                received_bytes += chunk.length;
                showDownloadingProgress(received_bytes, total_bytes);
            })
            .pipe(outStream);
};

function showDownloadingProgress(received, total) {
    var platform = "win32"; // Form windows system use win32 for else leave it empty
    var percentage = ((received * 100) / total).toFixed(2);
    process.stdout.write((platform == 'win32') ? "\033[0G": "\r");
    process.stdout.write(percentage + "% | " + received + " bytes downloaded out of " + total + " bytes.");
}
```

Usage :

```
getInstallerFile("http://example.com/bar.zip","bar.zip");
```

Comment: Perfectly working just need to declare platform variable and INSTALLER_FILE to file name to save

Comment: Super nice live preview in console ❤️

Answer (score 9):

Using the cool [node-request-progress](https://github.com/IndigoUnited/node-request-progress) module, you could do something like this in es2015:

```
import { createWriteStream } from 'fs'
import request from 'request'
import progress from 'request-progress'

progress(request('http://foo.com/bar.zip'))
 .on('progress', state => {

   console.log(state)

   /*
   {
       percentage: 0.5,        // Overall percentage (between 0 to 1)
       speed: 554732,          // The download speed in bytes/sec
       size: {
         total: 90044871,      // The total payload size in bytes
         transferred: 27610959 // The transferred payload size in bytes
       },
       time: {
         elapsed: 36.235,      // The total elapsed seconds since the start (3 decimals)
         remaining: 81.403     // The remaining seconds to finish (3 decimals)
       }
   }
   */

  })
  .on('error', err => console.log(err))
  .on('end', () => {})
  .pipe(createWriteStream('bar.zip'))
```

Answer (score 4):

In case someone wants to know the progress without the use of other library but only request, then you can use the following method :

```
function downloadFile(file_url , targetPath){
    // Save variable to know progress
    var received_bytes = 0;
    var total_bytes = 0;

    var req = request({
        method: 'GET',
        uri: file_url
    });

    var out = fs.createWriteStream(targetPath);
    req.pipe(out);

    req.on('response', function ( data ) {
        // Change the total bytes value to get progress later.
        total_bytes = parseInt(data.headers['content-length' ]);
    });

    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        // Update the received bytes
        received_bytes += chunk.length;

        showProgress(received_bytes, total_bytes);
    });

    req.on('end', function() {
        alert("File succesfully downloaded");
    });
}

function showProgress(received,total){
    var percentage = (received * 100) / total;
    console.log(percentage + "% | " + received + " bytes out of " + total + " bytes.");
    // 50% | 50000 bytes received out of 100000 bytes.
}

downloadFile("https://static.pexels.com/photos/36487/above-adventure-aerial-air.jpg","c:/path/to/local-image.jpg");
```

The `received_bytes` variable saves the total of every sent chunk length and according to the `total_bytes`, the progress is retrieven.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a module that just does what you want: [status-bar](https://github.com/gagle/node-status-bar).

```
var bar = statusBar.create ({ total: res.headers["content-length"] })
    .on ("render", function (stats){
      websockets.send (stats);
    })

req.pipe (bar);
```

Comment: Yeah, initially I used your module but I wanted to be able to display a progress bar to the user in the GUI with websockets.

Comment: You can do that. When the render function is called, send to the client the status bar. It is a string, you can do anything with it.

Comment: Right, but at some point it's easier to write something yourself than parse the string of another module. :)
Appreciate the tip though.

Comment: I updated the module 4 days ago. Now it doesn't return strings, it returns raw data, so you can render the status bar in the server or in the client. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Those look like great updates! I like how well documented it is. I'll definitely be considering it for future use.