# Node-Webkit file download progress

Tags: node.js, download, node-webkit, save-as

I have the following link in my Node-Webkit app

```
<a id="updateAppVersion" href="http://<some_path>/newVersion.zip">New version available</a>
```

This link works fine, it displays the 'save as' dialog and the user can save the file normally.

My question is, is there an easy way to display the download progress inside the app like browsers do or i need to create my own? (if so how?).

Currently nothing is displayed when the user chooses the download location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that nwjs includes this feature. If you choose to write your own mechanism, try [request-progress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-progress):

> Tracks the download progress of a request made with mikeal/request,
>   giving insight of various metrics including progress percent, download
>   speed and time remaining

check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323152/get-download-progress-in-node-js-with-request) for more options.

Comment: i managed to create my own mechanism with request-progress, the only problem is that the user can't choose the download location, but i'll accept it as an answer.