# What is the best way to download a big file in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

The below server code is working fine for 5GB file using
 `wget http://localhost:11146/base/bigFile.zip` but not using client side code.

> Server side code.

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var filename = "base/bigFile.zip";

var serv = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var stat = fs.statSync(filename);
    res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Length": stat.size});
    var fReadStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
    fReadStream.on('data', function (chunk) {
       if(!res.write(chunk)){
           fReadStream.pause();
       }
   });
   fReadStream.on('end', function () {
      res.end();
   });
   res.on("drain", function () {
      fReadStream.resume();
   });
});

serv.listen(1114);
```

> Client side code using Request module. What is wrong in this code?

```
var request = require('request')
request('http:/localhost:11146/base/bigFile.zip', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
```

> error for above client side code is below -

```
error: Error: Invalid protocol
    at Request.init (/Users/air/Projects/node_modules/request/request.js:338:51)
    at new Request (/Users/air/Projects//node_modules/request/request.js:105:8)
    at request (/Users/air/Projects/Vertico/Vertico-CLI/node_modules/request/index.js:53:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/air/Projects/req.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
statusCode: undefined
body: undefined
```

> I revised client side to use `wget` shell process instead of request package, that code is below, the problem is - I am not able to see nice download progress of wget, any work around for this code, such that I can see the progress bar in child process.

```
const fs = require('fs');
   const child_process = require('child_process');

   var workerProcess = child_process.spawn('wget', ['-O','fdsf.zip', 'http://localhost:11146/base/bigFile.zip']);

   workerProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
     console.log('stdout: ' + data);
   });

   workerProcess.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
     //console.log('stderr: ' + data);
   });

   workerProcess.on('close', function (code) {
      console.log('Download Completed' + code);
   });
```

So finally I want to know how to download a file using client side code written in nodejs?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

---

### `request` module is deprecated

It is recommended to use active modules. My personal preference is [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got)
Please refer [got streams](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/blob/HEAD/documentation/3-streams.md) for examples.
Another alternative is [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

---

Easiest way is to use `request` module

Here you are trying to store entire result in memory and console log it. 5GB is pretty much large, either you must increase Node.js memory limit (not recommended) or you must use streams. See the [streaming example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#streaming) below from `request` npm documentation:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');
request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png'))
```

You must pipe the response, so that whether is 1MB or 1GB or 1TB, only a fraction of the file will be in memory and it will be written to disk as soon as possible. You can use the same approach using Node.js built in functions, but implementation will be difficult and be like re-inventing the wheel when `request` module is there.

For **download with progress** you can use `request-progress` module along with `request` module, see the example below ([taken from their documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-progress#usage)):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var progress = require('request-progress');
 
// The options argument is optional so you can omit it 
progress(request('https://az412801.vo.msecnd.net/vhd/VMBuild_20141027/VirtualBox/IE11/Windows/IE11.Win8.1.For.Windows.VirtualBox.zip'), {
    // throttle: 2000,                    // Throttle the progress event to 2000ms, defaults to 1000ms 
    // delay: 1000,                       // Only start to emit after 1000ms delay, defaults to 0ms 
    // lengthHeader: 'x-transfer-length'  // Length header to use, defaults to content-length 
})
.on('progress', function (state) {
    // The state is an object that looks like this: 
    // { 
    //     percent: 0.5,               // Overall percent (between 0 to 1) 
    //     speed: 554732,              // The download speed in bytes/sec 
    //     size: { 
    //         total: 90044871,        // The total payload size in bytes 
    //         transferred: 27610959   // The transferred payload size in bytes 
    //     }, 
    //     time: { 
    //         elapsed: 36.235,        // The total elapsed seconds since the start (3 decimals) 
    //         remaining: 81.403       // The remaining seconds to finish (3 decimals) 
    //     } 
    // } 
    console.log('progress', state);
})
.on('error', function (err) {
    // Do something with err 
})
.on('end', function () {
    // Do something after request finishes 
})
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('IE11.Win8.1.For.Windows.VirtualBox.zip'));
```

Comment: I guess you will have to tap in between writing to file and do some calculations using the content-length from response headers and the bytes received during each event.  There could be modules, if I come across one, will let you know

Comment: @user2979152 See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323152/get-download-progress-in-node-js-with-request for download with progress

Comment: Really helpful answer. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
var request = require('request')
request('http://localhost:11146/base/bigFile.zip', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My version of code .

```
const fs = require( 'fs' );
const request = require( 'request' );
const progress = require( 'request-progress' );
const pre = '----';
const downloadManager = function ( url, filename ) {
    progress( request( url ), {
        throttle: 500
    } ).on( 'progress', function ( state ) {
        process.stdout.write( pre + '' + ( Math.round( state.percent * 100 ) ) + "%" );
    } ).on( 'error', function ( err ) {
        console.log( 'error :( ' + err );
    } ).on( 'end', function () {
        console.log( pre + '100% \n Download Completed' );
    } ).pipe( fs.createWriteStream( filename ) );
}
downloadManager( 'http://localhost:4181', 's.zip' );
```