# Is there a way to get downloaded bytes with express?

Tags: node.js, express

I use express manage download files like bellow:

```
    app.use("*", function (req, res, next) {
...
      res.download(filepath);
...
    });
```

and I want to create a download process bar, Is there a way to get downloaded bytes?

Comment: This is a problem to be solved on the client-side.
I guess that every library/package you would use on the client-side in order to retrieve the file has such capabilities.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get download progress in Node.js with request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323152/get-download-progress-in-node-js-with-request)